# Zeros of eigenforms at a given elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $N$ be an integer and $s \in X_1(N)(\mathbb C) = \Gamma_1(N) \backslash \mathbb H^*$, then one can define $T(s,N)$ to be the number of eigenforms in $S_2(\Gamma_1(N))$ that have a zero at $s$ [1].

The thing I'm interested in is how $T(s,N)$ behaves asymptotically when one restricts $N$ to be prime. To be precise, let $\pi_N: X_1(N)(\mathbb C) \to X_1(1)(\mathbb C)$ be the map that forgets the point of order $N$, and fix a point $s_1 \in X_1(1)(\mathbb C)$.

Does:
$$\limsup_{N\textrm{ prime, }s \in \pi_N^{-1}(s_1)} T(s,N)$$ exist for all $s_1$?

If not does one at least have that for all $s_1$:
$$\limsup_{N\textrm{ prime, }s \in \pi_N^{-1}(s_1)} \frac{ T(s,N) }{\dim_{\mathbb C} S_2(\Gamma_1(N))} = 0.$$

Note that these questions are easy if $s_1  \in X_1(N)(\mathbb C) \setminus X_1(N)(\overline{\mathbb Q})$ since then $T(s,N) = 0$ for all $s \in \pi_N^{-1}(s_1)$ because zeros of eigenforms are algebraic.

[1]: I view elements of $S_2(\Gamma_1(N))$ as sections of the line bundle $\Omega^1_{X_1(N)(\mathbb C)}$ in order to determine wether they have a zero. This is to make the eigenforms to have no zeros at the cusps.

Comment: In general cuspidal eigenforms $\omega_f$ with $f \in S_2(\Gamma(N))$ may have zeros at the cusps, but in your setting ($N$ prime) they probably don't.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just learned that a lot of things that I know about for the Hecke algebra of $\Gamma_0(N)$ and $\Gamma_1(N)$ are not true for $\Gamma(N)$. For example $S_2(\Gamma(N))$ does not necessarily admit a basis of eigenforms. So the answer to the question no longer means what I thought it would mean. I've changed the question accordingly. An answer to the question with $\Gamma_1$ repaced by $\Gamma_0$ would also be already interesting.

Comment: There are examples of elliptic curves $E/\mathbf{Q}$ such that the modular parametrization $X_0(N) \to E$ ramifies at some cusp, see e.g. Delaunay's thesis or http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/francois.brunault/recherche/ephi.pdf . In this case the form $f_E(z) dz$ does vanish at some cusp of $X_0(N)$ (or equivalently $X_1(N)$). But if $N$ is prime (or more generally $N$ squarefree) this doesn't happen, because of the action of Atkin-Lehner operators.

Comment: Dear Maarten, if this helps a little, I have done some computation which suggests that the zeros of rational eigenforms on $\Gamma_0(N)$ all lie in the subset of points $(E_1, E_2)$ in $X_0(N)$ such that $j(E_1)$ and $j(E_2)$ are conjugates under Galois. I haven't done anything with $\Gamma_1(N)$ so it'll be interesting. May I ask why you are interested in the above question? Thanks! -- hao